# Avoiding pagebreak after newline in theorem

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, theorems

This might be of relevance:

1. [Theorem environment - line break after label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37797/theorem-environment-line-break-after-label)
2. [pagebreak and amsmath theorem environment issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203649/pagebreak-and-amsmath-theorem-environment-issue/203684#203684)
3. [Avoid page break in theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30120/avoid-page-break-in-theorem/)

---

### Situation

I used the information provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43967/74942) to come up with this `break`-style:

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}
{2em} %spaceabove
{} %spacebelow
{} %\itshape} %bodyfont
{-1em} %indentamt
{\bfseries} %headfont
{} %headpunct
{\newline} %headspace
{
    \thmnumber{#2}\thmname{ #1}%
    \thmnote{ (#3) }
    } %headspec
```

**Note** that I have no control over where my theorems are going to be placed, as they are imported into a main file and a compendium (using [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297389/import-several-parts-of-file-at-once/297410#297410)).

### Attempts

Moreover I tried to put `\unskip\pagebreak` (from [here (2.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203684/74942)) behind `\newline` in headspace as well as behind `(#3)` in headspec. This, however, achieved the opposite: pagebreaks after each theorem header.

Unfortunately I do not have enough insight in LaTeX to adapt [this (3.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30120/avoid-page-break-in-theorem/) to my needs. It will produce crammed pages with peculiar indentation on some theorems and alike, plus, it does not completely fix the problem (I got at least 1 instance of the very same problem in my compendium).

### Question

## **How to avoid a page-break after the theorem-title when using my own theoremstyle that breaks the line.**

---

---

### Update:

1. after try out alexraasch suggestion

`\nobreak` produces widows and orphans (at least title + first line) instead of breaking beforehand. 
Plus I do use `\newcommand{\spaceBeforeEnumOnly}{~\vspace{-1em}}` in case a theorem or alike only consists of nothing but an enumeration - adding `\nobreak` did not work here.

2. after adding the penalties

[image: example - showing the enumerate issues] 
[image: example2]

Personally I think this is rather unaesthetic, but LaTeX probably doesn't even recognize those as unpleasing. The first one appears more often and also in combination with the aforementioned `\spaceBeforeEnumOnly`.

Comment: Try adding `\breakpenalty=10000` or `\nobreak` in the headspec.

Comment: @alexraasch, `\breakpenalty=10000` produces an error.  `\nobreak` does have some impact, though it produces widows and orphans (at least title + first line) instead of breaking beforehand. Plus I do use 
`\newcommand{\spaceBeforeEnumOnly}{~\vspace{-1em}}` in case a theorem or alike only consists of nothing but a enumeration - adding `\nobreak` did not work here.

Comment: So, where do you want to allow pagebreaks in a theorem, or none at all?

Comment: @alexraasch, I would like to have pagebreaks rather before or if the theorem is really long (>= 5~6 lines or enum items) somewhere inside. The problem is mostly only relevant if theorems have a description on one page and some result on another.

Comment: Ahm, well, I have to do a little guess work. You could also try to keep `\nobreak` in the headspec and add `\widowpenalty=5000` and `\clubpenalty=5000` to your document. If that doesn't work set these penalties to 10000.

Comment: @alexraasch, adding penalties doesn't yield the desired result. It might change minor things, though the real buggers prevail (see update).

Comment: Well, I think the pictures in your 2nd update don't look too bad. I mean there has to be a break somewhere eventually.